# Best Algorithm to Invite People to Party

Tags: algorithm, math, tree, hierarchy, dynamic-programming

I'm new here, but have question found in my text book.  Unfortunately it has no answers so I was wondering if someone could please help.  The question is:

> You are given the task of spreading invitations within a company. You only have
>   the time to talk to a certain amount of people, but you are guaranteed that if
>   you invite somebody, they will invite their boss, that person will
>   invite their boss, and so on, all the way up to the CEO. You have mapped out
>   the entire company hierarchy, and assigned a value to each person,
>   indicating how valuable it would be to invite them. Given this setup and a
>   limit on the number of people you can speak with, you want to compute the optimal
>   set of people to invite. An optimal set of people will maximize the total
>   value of all persons invited, directly or indirectly, by your selection.
>
> There will be exactly one person, the CEO, with no boss in the hierarchy. All
>   other people will eventually answer to this person on the command chain, but not
>   necessarily directly.
>
> You are guaranteed that each person will have at most one boss, but that boss
>   may have another in turn. For example, person A may have a boss B, whose boss is
>   C, whose boss is D, whose boss is the CEO. Thus influencing person A will
>   automatically influence B, C, D, and the CEO.
>
> Different employees may have bosses in common in the command chain. You DO NOT
>   obtain additional value for influencing a person more than once. For example, if
>   A and B both answer directly to the CEO, and you influence both, you will
>   receive a value of val(A)+val(B)+val(CEO), not val(A)+val(B)+2val(CEO).
>
> Given a positive integer j, select the j people that will ultimately result
>   in the greatest overall value.

I know that the brute force approach is to just search the list for the max value j times, but that is not very helpful.  I think there is a dynamic programming approach but my attempt did not always provide the correct answer.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It is a bit more complicated than selecting the lowest people hierarchically speaking : some of them might have a common ancestor !

Comment: Exactly - One approach I tried was to loop through these lowest level employees, select the max, and update the values of the others, but it is still extremely slow and definitely not optimal.

Comment: To clarify, what's the constraint—the number of people that can attend the party, or the number of invites you can write? (Not the same because some people get invited indirectly)

Comment: OP, have you tried a greedy algorithm? Can you prove it's optimal? If not, when does it go wrong? Does that inspire a new algorithm?

Comment: Vote to keep open—this is a well-written carefully defined algorithms problem. (Though it would be better with an example.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let V[e, k] be the maximum value of issuing k invitations to e and e's direct and indirect subordinates, ignoring the value of all direct and indirect supervisors of e. If employee e has no subordinates, then the base case is

```
V[e, k], k = 0 = 0
V[e, k], k > 0 = val(e).
```

If employee e0 has two subordinates, e1 and e2, then the recurrence is

```
V[e0, k], k = 0 = 0
V[e0, k], k > 0 = max over j of val(e0) + V[e1, j] + V[e2, k - j].
```

The naive convolution with more than two employees is too slow, so we have to convolve the first pair and then convolve in the rest. I'm going to omit the details.

Comment: @David - it is definitely optimal to choose the employee with the greatest marginal value.  Do you have some pseudocode to show this can be completed in less than O(n^k) though? That would be a brute-force style approach.

Comment: @AgirMahad: If you mark already-invited people, then to score a particular person, you just need to walk up the tree until you hit the first already-invited person (every person above that is necessarily already invited too).  That will take at most n steps, and there are at most n people to score, so finding the best person to add will be at worst O(n^2).  There are k steps, so overall it's O(kn^2).

Comment: Actually @Nemo seems to be right.  That Wikipedia page even mentions the Maximum Coverage problem, which is NP-hard, and which is only a slight generalisation of this problem.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yep, I'm not awake. The answer has been completely rewritten.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat - not sure i understand what you mean by convolve? I understand the base cases and the case where there are two employee, but am not sure what you mean as how to expand this to multiple subordinates (3, 4 or more).  Any further help would be awesome.  Thank you for you're helping me to understand better.  Update: is your recurrence for 2 subordinate O(nk^2)?

Comment: @AgirMahad Yes to your update. The naive 3-subordinate version would be `max over j1, j2 of val(e0) + V[e1, j1] + V[e2, j2] + V[e3, k - j1 - j2]`, which is O(nk^3). To keep the exponent from blowing up with more subordinates, we rewrite to `max over j1 of max over j2 of ...` and then a bunch of the computations for the interior max are shared.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Is O(nk^2) the best then? I think I may have come up with a O(nk) approach but not sure if it works.  I was trying to think of divide and conquer approach where I divide hierarchy by subordinates but there is no clean way to identify which is best without first reaching the bottom of that respective path.  It could also be converted to longest path problem, but then it would be a O(nk^2 + ..) run time roughly.  Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this answer assumes the values for inviting people are all non-negative.

This problem can be solved using a greedy algorithm. Let us first discuss the case where the values are all equal, so we are just trying to invite the maximum number of people. The key observation is that in any optimal solution, you should always pick the person with the largest number of direct or indirect superiors. Here's a brief explanation of why: suppose person `X` has the most superiors, and you have some selections that don't include person `X`. Consider the person `Y` among your selections which shares the most superiors with `X`. Then, you can do better by selecting `X` instead of `Y`.

So in the first step, we can always greedily select the person with the most superiors. Then, the problem reduces to the same problem on several smaller trees. For example, suppose we are selecting 3 invitees from the following tree:

```
       A
   B       C
 D   E   F   G
H I J K L M N O
```

Our first selection will be `H`, which automatically gives us `D`, `B`, and `A`. Then, it remains to select 2 from the three trees

```
I   E      C
   J K   F   G
        L M N O
```

The next best choice is `L`, and so on.

We can do this efficiently, because we just need to keep track of the deepest child (not necessarily direct child) of each node, which we can compute beforehand. Then, we need some kind of priority queue data structure to select the best tree to pick from. If you are selecting `k` people from a hierarchy of size `n`, this should give a `O(n + k log n)` algorithm.

To extend this to the case where values may be unequal, basically the exact same idea works, except instead of depth, you need to calculate the total value of all superiors. For each node `X`, you keep track of the child `Y` which has the largest total value along the path between `Y` and `X`.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the greedy approach if the value of a node can be negative.

Comment: Good point, this only works if the values are non-negative, which I assumed to be the case. But I guess the problem makes sense with negative values too.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a [graph problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)). You can use the idea of connected components to realise a solution to this.

- First iteration will cover everyone in the company where you will determine who the CEO is and who is directly below him.
- Take each of the bosses directly below the CEO as the initial set of components.
- Then for each other person, you will use dfs to associate them with a 2nd level boss (This is the dynamic approach).
- You want to do this last part in such a way that if `person F` is the boss of `person E`, who in turn is the boss of `person D`, ... all the way down to `person A`, then you want after the dfs to be able to say in O(1) time that person F is the boss of person A and vice versa.

Remember to keep a count for each boss where the count will be the sum of the values of all persons below him, and optionally keep track of the number of people.

The optimal case would be that you find all people lower in chain first, otherwise the algorithm should run in O(nk) where k is the maximum chain from bottom to top